# Idiomatic way to timeout websocket.Dial in go?

Tags: go

I have code like the following:

```
_, err := websocket.Dial("wss://remote-server", "", "http://localhost")

if (err == nil) {
  fmt.Println("Worked!")
} else {
  fmt.Println("Fail")
}
```

When `remote-server` is down, it takes 60s to timeout. I found `websocket.SetDeadline` (http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket#Conn.SetDeadline), but I don't have a connection yet to apply it to. I can pass a `Config` to `DialConfig`, but I can't see where to specify a timeout doing that.

I found https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/Timeouts, is this how I have to do it? How do I correctly pass the error code back from the goroutine?

Comment: Normally you'd use `net.DialTimeout()` if you want a timeout, but websocket just calls `Dial()` instead. You may want to [file an issue](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/list) about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I havent used the go websocket package yet but from what I can infer from the documentation one should probably use [net.DialTimeout(...)](http://godoc.org/net#DialTimeout) coupled with [websocket.NewClient(...)](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket#NewClient)

The [source of DialConfig](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/websocket/client.go?repo=net#80) uses the same method but limited to net.Dial.

Comment: This. Create your client (*Conn) first, set the required deadlines and then use it to make the call.

Comment: sorry for accepting so late, didn't see it come in at the time and it just caught my eye now.